# Struts2 send information to other action

Tags: struts2

I have two action list and add. When i go to add action from list action then add action is open. After Filling form and submit, Page is redirected to list page and show successfully added message.
**I did like that**
I send update true from add page and on list page i checked update true with referrer add page url then show successfully added message. 
**But problem is**
 when I press F5 and click on refresh icon, message appear again.

I want to know that how i will send information from action to action in Struts2. So that after clicking refersh icon and pressing F5, this information is delete.

Answer (score 0):

This is the well known problem of double submission. If the problem is only reloading with **F5**, the easiest way for you would be just capturing the event. Like this:

```
// keep old onkeyup event
var oldwkeyup = window.onkeyup;
window.onkeyup = wkeyup;
function wkeyup(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 116) {// F5
        return false;
    }
    // try to execute the old event
    try {
        oldwkeyup();
    } catch (E) {}
}
```

Or do the same with jQuery.

Anyway the best solution should be **Post/Redirect/Get** method but for this, you should change a bit the way you are doing the things in your application and may be a bit confusing. Take a look at [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and [THIS](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post). For *struts* you have another example [HERE](http://javamentors.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-avoid-duplicate-submission-using.html).

Hope this helps.